# why substr() wrong counts for Arabic string?

Tags: php, substring

I have a php variable that is contained 9 Arabic character. But when I set `9` in the `substr()`, the output is `4` character. Why ? How can I fix it ?

[here](http://3v4l.org/4IRCm) is my demo.

and here is my codes:

```
$str = 'سلام جهان'; 
// the number of character: 9 character {س|ل|ا|م| |ج|ه|ا|ن}

echo substr($str, 0, 9);

// output: سلام

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the multi-byte equivalent:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$string = "سلام جهان";
$mystring = mb_substr($string,5,1);
echo $mystring;
```

You can also set the flag using my_substr:

```
mb_substr($string, 5,1, "utf-8");
```

Comment: to help the community, kindly mark the answer as correct.

Comment: please add this to your answer: also you can use of `mb_substr($string, 5,1, "utf-8");`

Comment: Absolutely. Good idea.